# Replacing a value in string with a value in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, replace, identifier

Could you assist me with replacing an identifier value with a value from a dictionary. So the code looks like follow

```
    #string holds the value we want to output
    s = '${1}_p${guid}s_${2}'
    d = {1: 'bob', 2: '123abc', 3: 'CA', 4: 'smith' }
```

I want to be able to replace ${1} with bob and ${2} with 123abc, I only want to change a value if the value inside ${} is just a number then, replace it with the value within the dictionary.

```
   output = 'bob_p${guid}s_123abc'
```

I tried using template module, but it did not sub in the value.

Comment: Where do you get the string `s` from? Do you have the freedom to change how `s` is formatted?

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried and how it didn't work?

Comment: s comes from a property file that could be edited at anytime.

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.findall` to get the values to be replaced.

```
>>> import re
>>> to_replace = re.findall('{\d}',s)
>>> to_replace
=> ['{1}', '{2}']
```

Now go through the `to_replace` values and perform `.replace()`.

```
>>> for r in to_replace: 
        val = int(r.strip('{}'))
        try:                                     #since d[val] may not be present
               s = s.replace('$'+r, d[val])
        except:
               pass 

>>> s
=> 'bob_p${guid}s_123abc'
```

#driver values:

```
IN : s = '${1}_p${guid}s_${2}'
IN : d = {1: 'bob', 2: '123abc', 3: 'CA', 4: 'smith' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. So, I know what to replace for each key in the dictionary. I think the code is self explanatory.

```
s = '${1}_p${guid}s_${2}'
d = {1: 'bob', 2: '123abc', 3: 'CA', 4: 'smith' }

for i in d:
    s = s.replace('${'+str(i)+'}',d[i])
print(s)
```

Output:

```
bob_p${guid}s_123abc
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the standard string `.format()` method. [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) is a link to the docs with the relevant info. You might find the following quote from the page particularly useful.

```
"First, thou shalt count to {0}"  # References first positional argument
"Bring me a {}"                   # Implicitly references the first positional argument
"From {} to {}"                   # Same as "From {0} to {1}"
"My quest is {name}"              # References keyword argument 'name'
"Weight in tons {0.weight}"       # 'weight' attribute of first positional arg
"Units destroyed: {players[0]}"   # First element of keyword argument 'players'.
```

Here is your code modified based on using the `.format()` method.

```
    # string holds the value we want to output
d = {1: 'bob', 2: '123abc', 3: 'CA', 4: 'smith'}

s = ''
try:
    s = '{0[1]}_p'.format(d) + '${guid}' + 's_{0[2]}'.format(d)
except KeyError:
    # Handles the case when the key is not in the given dict. It will keep the sting as blank. You can also put
    # something else in this section to handle this case. 
    pass
print s
```