# Replace elements in string using references from list with dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I want replace parameters in SQL scrip in string format using references from list with dictionary inside. This is example SQL script:

```
sql = "SELECT DISTINCT id, channel AS value FROM ${source} WHERE channel IN (${channel});"
```

All of the queries are in this structure:

```
{'name': 'example', 'description': 'example1', 'sql': 'SELECT DISTINCT id, channel AS value FROM ${source} WHERE channel IN (${channel});'}
```

The dictionary looks like this:

```
my_dict = [{"source":"table_name","channel":["abc","abcd"]}]
```

The desired output is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pnr, channel AS value FROM table_name WHERE channel IN ("abc", "abcd");
```

Note: It is possible the channel parameter to have single value: `my_dict = [{"source":"table_name","channel":["abc"]}]` This is very important to have in mind.

I was thinking to `.split` the query and to replace the parameters, but for some reason it is not working and the channels are without quotes. I need them in quotes, so the query can be executed later.

```
queries = sql.split()
final_string = ' '.join(str(my_dict.get(word, word)) for word in queries)
```

Another solution I found, but could not implemented for my case : [Replacing a value in string with a value in a dictionary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46914923/replacing-a-value-in-string-with-a-value-in-a-dictionary-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

What you have is not a dictionary, but a list. If you are interested in the dictionary at the first position of the list you could use an [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) and do:

```
>>> sql = f"SELECT DISTINCT id, channel AS value FROM {my_dict[0]['source']} WHERE channel IN {tuple(my_dict[0]['channel'])};"
>>> sql
"SELECT DISTINCT id, channel AS value FROM table_name WHERE channel IN ('abc', 'abcd');"
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! How can I use this if i have multiple queries inside a dictionary and they are the values?